# Shell script to fetch log (json format) file between date and timestamp

Tags: shell, timestamp

The log file folder structure is \Mainfolder\folder1\year(2020)\month(07)\date(24)*.json.
Ex: \Mainfolder\folder1\2020\07\24\filename.json.
The .json file is getting created every hour, like 00:00:00_00:59:59.json, 01:00:00_01:59:59.json and so on.
I have to search under the .json file with following inputs.
My current inputs are keyword, start date. Currently I'm taking that Date, and keyword and able to get the output in a file.

Current script for your reference:
`#!/bin/bash`
`set +x`
`DTE=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y-v%H%m%s")`
`Date=$1`         #yyyy/mm/dd
`Keyword=$2`      #keyword in string
`Start_Time=$3`   #hh:mm
`End_Time=$4`     #hh:mm
`BKT=bucketpath/mainfolder/`
`output=$(gsutil cat -h gs://bucketpath/mainfolder/"$Date"/* | egrep  "$Keyword")`
`echo $output >> $"/tmp/folder/logoutput-$DTE"`
`gsutil cp -r /tmp/folder/logoutput-$DTE gs://bucketpath/mainfolder/`

I have to add end date, Start_Time & End_Time and search in the .json file and get the output in a file like above.
I tried to use awk & sed, but i'm unable to get the output.
Could anyone help me on this script please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't seek help without doing any research, i have tried possibilities whatever i could do and seeking assistance here.

awk ' /2020-07-01 08:15/,/2020-07-01 08:17/ ' filename.json > output_log.txt

awk -v from="08:14" -v to="08:17" '$1>=from && $1<=to' filename.json

cat mfplog-22-07-2020-v20071595419591 | grep 2020/07/01:23:3[4-7]: > fetchlog

egrep "^\[2014-04-07 23:59:58\]" test.txt -A 10000 | egrep "^\[2014-04-08 00:00:03\]" -B 10000

Comment: please consider this is valid post and assist me.

Comment: cat filename | sed -n 's/\("timestamp":\)/\1/p'  ---- this command fetching the particular string
cat test | sed -n "/23:32/,/23:36/ p" ---- this command helps to fetch log between timeframe.
I wanted to join both the above mentioned commands. can someone helps me in this.
I tried several options but i couldn't achieve, please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared following script to collect the logs between date and timestamp along with keyword. My log file is in .json format.
The reason for posting here is, it might help someone who is looking for similar script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
DTE=$(date "+%d-%m-%Y-v%H%m%s")
startdate=$1
enddate=$2
start_Time=$3
end_Time=$4
keyword=$5
BKT=storage/folder
i=$start_time
i1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$i")
j=$end_time
j1=$(sed 's/.\{3\}$//' <<< "$j")
curr="$startdate"
while true; do
   echo "$curr"
   [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break
   output=$(gsutil cat -h gs://storage/folder/"$curr"/"$i1:00:00_$j1:59:59*" | sed -n '/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$i':/,/"timestamp":"[^"]*T'$j':/p' | grep "$keyword")
   echo $output >> $"/tmp/folder/mylog-$DTE"
   curr=$( date +%Y/%m/%d --date "$curr +1 day" )
   done
gsutil cp -r /tmp/folder/mylog-$DTE gs://storage/folder/
```

Comment: is anyone can help me to add a loop within while loop to increase the start_time & end_time every one hour and fetch the logs between the hours.
Let say start_time 00:00 end_time is 02:59, i want the loop increase every one hour and fetch the logs between start_time and end_time.